# How to display a widget on home page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display subscribe2 plugin's widget on home page. I inserted sidebar into the template:

```
<div style="display: none">
    <?php get_sidebar('home'); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and used `the_widget` function with Calendar for testing purposes:

```
<?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Calendar' ); ?>
```

This code shows nothing. So how can I show a widget manually on any page and particularly the subscribe2 widget on front page?

Comment: It's set as `<div style="display: none">` that's why

Comment: Try using dynamic_sidebar() function.

Comment: @yeshansachithak The widget is not inside sidebar, I put `the_widget()` a bit higher in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the Subscribe2 Plugin's `Widget` into the `Primary Sidebar` in the `Widget` section under the `Appearance` menu and use the below code to display the `Widget` anywhere in the template file.

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
```

If you are inserting `Widget` in `Content Sidebar` or `Footer Widget Area` use 'sidebar-2' and 'sidebar-3' respectively in the code.